# Passing objects from a pool to a runnable class

Tags: java, multithreading, object-pooling

I have an pool of objects in a blockingQueue. Now i want to assign objects from the queue to a thread and use it inside the run method.

What is the best way of doing it?

Here is a sample code i am using to build the pool:

```
public class ConsumerPool {

private static Logger log;

//building consumer Pool
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public BlockingQueue<OAuthConsumer> buildConsumerPool() {

    BlockingQueue<OAuthConsumer> consumerObjectsQueue = null;
    try {
        //setting the config path
        PropertyHandler.setConfigPath(propertiesMain);
        String twitterPath = PropertyHandler.getProperty("twitterPath");

        //setting config for twitter
        PropertyHandler.setConfigPath(twitterPath);
        //Blocking Linked Queue

        consumerObjectsQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<OAuthConsumer>();


        //fetching required tokens for all apps
        String consumerKeySet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("consumerKey");
        String consumerSecretSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("consumerSecret");
        String accessTokenSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("accessToken");
        String tokenSecretSet = PropertyHandler.getProperty("tokenSecret");

        String[] splitconsumerKeys = consumerKeySet.split(",");
        String[] splitconsumerSecret = consumerSecretSet.split(".");
        String[] splitaccessToken = accessTokenSet.split(",");
        String[] splittokenSecret = tokenSecretSet.split(".");

        //creating consumer objects for each app
        for (int i= 0; i< splitconsumerKeys.length; i++) {
            log.info("constructing consumer object for twitter api " +i);
            String consumerKey = splitconsumerKeys[i];
            String consumerSecret = splitconsumerSecret[i];
            String accessToken = splitaccessToken[i];
            String tokenSecret = splittokenSecret[i];
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, tokenSecret);
            consumerObjectsQueue.put(consumer);
            log.info("added the consumer object to que pool");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return consumerObjectsQueue;
    }
}
```

That is used to build the object pool.

Here is the way i want to create threads.

```
public class MrRunnable implements Runnable {
private String toFireUrl;

MrRunnable(String url){
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // do some function here
}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We will create 500 threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        Runnable task = new MrRunnable("some new url");
        Thread worker = new Thread(task);
        //start the thread
        worker.start();
    }
}
```

}

Now i want to access the objects in the pool via a thread. In the main program should i pass the object from the consumer pool  to runnable class during the creation of MrRunnable Object or is there any other way i can do it ?

Comment: How about using a static variable of ConsumerPool

Comment: But will its scope be recognized within the run method of the MrRunnable?

Comment: If you define a Global class and declare a static variable of ConsumerPool. You can always access Global.Var_ConsumerPool in MrRunnable. Depends on what and how you manage the ConsumerPool data.

Comment: But is it the right practise to declare things globally? Cause i really did give it a thought before putting it on here and i felt declaring something globally might not be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the constructor of MrRunnable should get a reference to the queue

Comment: +1 if you want a Runnable to use a shared resource, the best approach is to pass it as an argument.  You could use a singleton, but avoid this trap if you can.